# Exit 1 if the total numbers input is not 8

Tags: c, algorithm

I want user to enter 8 numbers.
If they enter less than 8 numbers, the program will exit.

What if statement should I use?
Should I put in my loop sum += i then if sum not 8 then exit?

This is what I got so far but it doesn't work out:

```
int main() {
    int i, numb;
    int sum = 0;

    // the loop to enter 8 numb
    printf("enter 8 numbers");

    if (i=0;i<8;i++) {
        scanf("%d", &numb);
        sum =+i;
        if (sum < 8)
            exit(1);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you have written for this, or at least your attempt. Explain why you think it is not working and how you **think** you would fix it.

Your question is just gonna get closed at the minute because it shows little/no effort.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far???

Comment: @Taylor, Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want the user to enter 8 numbers and since you have not mentioned anything about the sum, I'll assume it doesn't matter what it is. Remove the inner if condition altogether and replace the outer if with a loop.

Here is the code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &numb);
    //Do whatever you want to do with the number here
```

Comment: And what if there wouldn't be 8 numbers at the input? Read the question once again, think again.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way the console works you can't tell where the `EOF` is. You can achieve what you want by checking the separators between the numbers. If you want the numbers to be no less than 8 on the same line, you can do it this way

```
int main() {
    int i, numb;
    int sum = 0;
    char separator=' ';
    // the loop to enter 8 numb
    printf("enter 8 numbers");
    for (i = 0; i<8; i++)
    {
        if (separator == '\n')//enter character encountered
            break;
        scanf("%d%c", &numb,&separator);
    }
    if (i < 8)
        exit(1);
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an algorithm which does exactly what you want:

```
 1. Set a counter to 0
 2. While not end of file (EOF) do

     1. Read a number
     2. Increase counter by 1

3. If sum counter equals 8, return 1, else return 0
```

---

and your code repaired (since you've finally posted what you tried to do):

```
int main()
{
    int i, numb, counter = 0;
    printf("enter 8 numbers");

    while(scanf("%d", &numb) != EOF)
    {   
        counter++;
    }

    if (counter < 8)
    {
        printf("not enough numbers\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/iiOl1A